# Simulate a 360 mouse movement inside a game using SendInput

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, mouse-cursor

Ok so, I have this code right now which makes the mouse cursor move to the right as long as you hold down the `Z` key on the keyboard.

**Code:**

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x5A))
{
    cMouseInput mInput;
    mInput.MouseMove(1, 0);  // Right
    //mInput.MouseMove(-1, 0); // Left
}
```

**The function:**

```
void cMouseInput::MouseMove(int X, int Y)
{
    double fScreenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 1;
    double fScreenHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 1;
    double fX = X * (65535.0f / fScreenWidth);
    double fY = Y * (65535.0f / fScreenHeight);

    INPUT mInput = { 0 };
    mInput.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    mInput.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    mInput.mi.dx = fX;
    mInput.mi.dy = fY;

    SendInput(1, &mInput, sizeof(INPUT));
}
```

Now, I want it to do a full circle spin(*a 360 basically*) inside a game with just **1 key press**.
And also **while** it is doing that spin, I want to execute another key-press 4 times.

I can't figure out a good way to do this.. maybe using a timer would be a good idea?

Like, `Start timer on key-press -> execute other key-press -> End timer and release key`

But how would I go about this?

Comment: Timer would do it. For full 360 rotation you can use: ``x = r * cos(theta), y = r * sin(theta)``. Just swap ``cos`` and ``sin`` for clockwise rotation

Comment: Do you just want to MoveUp-->(other key press)-->MoveRight-->(other key)-->MoveDown-->(other key)--->MoveLeft-->(other key)?  Or do you need more fine tuned angles, like moveup-->moveup/right-->moveright, etc?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I managed to do what I wanted using a simple timer loop. (Using `WaitForSingleObject`)

Comment: @Ryan
No, I simply wanted to do a full look-around with a key-press and the answer I posted does the job for me.. although i'm sure this could be done in a much, much better way..

Answer (score -2):

I managed to do what I wanted (in what might not be the best way, but it does what I intended for it to do..)

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(i1x1Value) & 1)
{
    cMouseInput mInput;

    int iCount = 0;
    HANDLE hTimer = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    while (iCount < 4)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, i1x1Sleep); // Wait for x amount
        mInput.MouseMove(50, 0); // Right

        iCount++; // Repeat 4 times
    }
    CloseHandle(hTimer);
}
```

If u have any suggestions to improve this, please do say.

Comment: You are creating an event object which you never actually use. This has got to be the most convoluted way to avoid calling `Sleep`.